# If $\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid Y \right] = 0$ does $\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid Y,Z \right] = 0$

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

$X,Y,Z$ are all random variables on the same probability space.

I think the title is false in general, but direction of a proof would be helpful. I also have some similar questions:

$$
\text{If  } \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] = 0 \ \& \ \mathbb{E}[Y \mid Z] = 0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X, Z ] = 0
$$

Let $\beta$ be a constant,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \beta X] = \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]$$

(not $=\beta\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]$)

Lastly, is $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X = \mu]$ the same thing as $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]$? If not, what is different between saying the expected value of $Y$ given a realization of $X$ oppose to the expected value of $Y$, given the random variable $X$?

While I'm at it, any suggestions of (somewhat rigorious) books that cover expectation well is appreciated. I am trying to get a very good understanding of it on a fundamental level. I have analysis texts, but something geared more toward just probability space may be better for me.

Comment: For the title: Consider, for example, the case when $Y$ is independent of $(X,Z)$. Also, perhaps you can define $X=Z$.

Comment: For the second (does $E[Y|X]=E[Y|Z]=0$ imply $E[Y|X,Z]=0$), the answer is "no," and there are some simple counter-examples.  What is the context here?

Comment: The easiest way to understand $E[Y|X]$ is to define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = E[Y|X=x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and then define $E[Y|X]=g(X)$ (so $E[Y|X]$ is a random function of $X$, i.e., a random variable).

Comment: Hm okay, thank you, this helps my understanding 

The actual question I am trying to answer is Econometrics related; to try and show that:

$\mathbb{E}[U_{iT}\mid Y_{i1},\cdots,Y_{i,T-1},\alpha_{i}] = 0$ given that $\mathbb{E}[U_{it}\mid \alpha_{i}] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[U_{it}\mid Y_{i0}] = 0$ Where $U_{it}$ is a white noise process with zero mean, finite variance. Additionally, this is an autoregression model from $Y_{it}$. 

My intuition was that I could show that $\mathbb{E}[U_{iT}\mid Y_{i1},\cdots,Y_{i,T-1},\alpha_{i}]$ is actually just

Comment: For a counterexample to the second one: take $Y,Z$ being (independent) random variables uniform on $\{0,1\}$, and set $X=(Y+Z)\mod 2 -1$. Then $X$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}$, $X$ is independent of $Y$, and $X$ is independent of $Z$, so that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]=0$; yet $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,Z]=X$.

Comment: is actually just going to be $\mathbb{E}[U_{iT}\mid (Y)'s, (\alpha)'s,(U)'s]$ and since the conditional expectation of each alone is zero, together they will still be zero. So far, it seems this logic may be incorrect though.

Comment: Michael, regarding the counterexample for the title:

Suppose $X = Z$, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y,Z] = X$ which is not necessarily zero? I understand this fine, given that $\mathbb{E}[F \mid F,G] = F$ always.

Comment: Clement C - 

First, how is $X$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}$? 

If $Y = 1, Z = 0$ then $X = (1 \mod 2)-1 = (1-1) = 0$ Or do you mean $X = (1 \mod (2-1))$? 

Either way, the logic of the proof holds, thank you.

Comment: @user43395 I messed up with the scaling. $Z+Y \mod 2$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$, so it should be $X = 2(Z+Y \mod 2)-1$ to get uniform on $\{-1,1\}$. This doesn't change the rest.